# How to avoid using a temporary table for this simple query

Tags: mysql, performance

How can I avoid using a temporary table for this query and still accomplishing the same goal?

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED 
SELECT DISTINCT id, view_count
  FROM
      screenshot_udb_affect_assoc
  INNER JOIN
      screenshot ON id = screenshot_id
  WHERE unit_id = 110 LIMIT 0, 6

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  screenshot_udb_affect_assoc ref screenshot_id,unit_id   unit_id 4   const   34  100.00  Using temporary
1   SIMPLE  screenshot  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   source_core.screenshot_udb_affect_assoc.screenshot...   1   100.00
```

I've updated the query to not use `RAND()` anymore and instead the `LIMIT` will be randomized via PHP.  Though it still shows that it's using a temporary table

Comment: Does `unit_id` belong to `screensho`t? How many screenshots are there with `unit_id = 110`? How many `screenshot_udb_affect_assoc` per `screenshot`?

Comment: Around 150 screenshots for a given unit, probably 12-15 units per screenshot

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what the new query looks like that you are producing (preferably with an EXPLAIN as well)?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  rnd_id, rnd_value
FROM    (
        SELECT  @cnt := COUNT(*) + 1,
                @lim := 6
        FROM    screenshot
        JOIN    screenshot_udb_affect_assoc
        ON      screenshot_id = id
        WHERE   unit_id = 110
        ) vars
STRAIGHT_JOIN
        (
        SELECT  r.*,
                @lim := @lim - 1
        FROM    (
                SELECT  id, view_count
                FROM    screenshot
                JOIN    screenshot_udb_affect_assoc
                ON      screenshot_id = id
                WHERE   unit_id = 110
                ) r 
        WHERE   (@cnt := @cnt - 1)
                AND RAND() < @lim / @cnt
        ) i
```

Explained in more detail in this article:

- [**Selecting random rows**](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/)

This still needs two scans on all rows satisfying the query, but no `filesort`.

Create the following indexes:

```
screenshot (unit_id)
screenshot_udb_affect_assoc (screenshot_id)
```

Comment: I hate not to use that, but if it requires two scans I really want to try to get down to 1 scan if I can.

Comment: @Webnet: you can replace the `COUNT(*)` with the rough estimate. The randomness will suffer a little from it, but it will complete in only one scan.

Answer (score 2):

`ORDER BY RAND()` automatically causes a temporary table to be created.

It works by creating a temporary table with a new column that is populated with random numbers.  It then performs the query against the temporary table using `ORDER BY`.

To avoid using a temporary table, you will have to find a new method of selecting random numbers.

The solution I have used before (which relies on rows not being deleted) is to do a `SELECT COUNT` on the table, then picking random numbers in that range and only selecting those rows.

There are a number of other solutions, but `ORDER BY RAND()` is not a good solution.